# Twig's attribute function : formatting numbers

Tags: symfony, twig

In a Symfony2 application, I use Twig's [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) function to display properties of a product on a generic manner : I have an array of names of properties, and cycling through it I display properties :

```
{% for property in arrayProperties %}
    {{ attribute(entity, property)|trans }}
{% endfor %}
```

These properties can be litteral OR numeric, eg:

- description : text
- number_of_X : integer
- size_of_Y   : float (scale=2)
- size_of_Z   : float (scale=5)

The problem is that float properties are displaying this way :

> size_of_Y : 0.42
>
> size_of_Z : 0.84848

While I would like to display **with a comma separator**, this way :

> size_of_Y : 0,42
>
> size_of_Z : 0,84848

It seems I can't use the [number_format](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html) function right after the attribute function since it will transform my **litteral** values in `0`'s, and even if I can find a way to test if the value displayed is a numeric or litteral value (a `is_numeric`ish function), I won't be able to determine the scale of the property (how many numbers after the comma I should display, which is the first argument of `number_format`).

Is there a generic way to change how Twig is displaying these properties ?

In my Twig's configuration (*config.yml*), I already have :

```
number_format:
    decimals: 0
    decimal_point: ','
    thousands_separator: ' '
```

Which seems to work for the rest of the application, where I don't use the `attribute` function to display properties.

Thanks !

Comment: You will probably need to write your own Twig extension to handle this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Wow ! At least now I know what twig extensions are for... I'll give it a try, thanks !

Comment: You should create an answer so i can validate it for others to see @CarlosGranados

Comment: You should take a look at the `localizednumber` filter: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html#localizednumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own Twig extension to handle this:

[Twig Extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Answer (score 1):

So define additional types in your `arrayProperties`, add a type and a scale so you can do tests in the loop and so you don't call `trans` for numeric values.

```
{% for property_name, property_infos in properties %}
    {% if property_infos.type == 'numeric' %}
        {{ attribute(obj, property_name)|number_format(property_infos.scale, ',', ',') }}<br/>
    {% else %}
        {{ attribute(obj, property_name)|trans }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but the application is complex and this solution will lack maintainability and will be fastidious to implement given the number of entities relying on this attribute() method in the application... Thanks though :)

Comment: So I don't undersand why you have a `arrayProperties` and `obj` , if you want to make the code clear you should only deal with obj and having a method that returns only the properties you want to display for this object.

Comment: That is what I have, actually my arrayProperties come from obj.getPropertiesToDisplay(). To retrieve the scale and type of properties would imply going through all the objects (a LOT) and find out scale & type for all the properties (a... LOT ! :)) for each one of these objects... !

Comment: So you could do an extension that read the attributes types through reflection.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution I opted for and it's working great ! Thanks ;)